# Something to remember (one) by

Tags: word-usage

> I don't really have anything to remember all those trips **by**.

What's the difference between

- I don't really have anything to remember all those trips **by**
- I don't really have anything to remember all those trips

And I want to know the grammar specifically of **by** there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the usual online dictionaries, I can't find a sense of 'by' that really fits. It's probably best to treat 'something to remember someone by' as a fixed expression. This view is supported by its inclusion in the [Farlex Idioms Dictionary and the Farlex Partners Idiom Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/something+to+remember+someone+by):

> *something to remember (one) by*
>
> A memento or keepsake to remind one of someone.
>
> *I'll miss you too. Here, keep my hat—something to remember me by.*
>
> ..........
>
> *something to remember somebody by* (informal)
>
> a punishment, especially a physical one:
>
> *If I ever catch you stealing my apples again, I’ll give you something to remember me by.*

If you really feel the need to break the expression down, you can compare with the unwieldy

*I don't really have anything by which to remember all those trips*

where 'by which' obviously means 'by means of which'. So this is perhaps best considered as the instrumental sense of 'by', though it's not a prototypical example such as we see with 'He managed to lose two stone by dieting'. Other examples of the broad instrumental usage are 'He did it by hand' and 'He travelled by car'.